# mathools' \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP with left-right default

Tags: mathtools

In the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\E[1]{\mathbb{E}}[]{}{#1}
\begin{document}
 \[ \E{\sum_{i=1}^N } \]
 \[ \E*{\sum_{i=1}^N } \]
\end{document}
```

The second pair of parentheses have `\left`, `\right` applied to them while the first one does not. Is it possible to switch the behavior? i.e., `\E` has `\left`, `\right` while `\E*` does not. I came up with:

```
\makeatletter%
\DeclareRobustCommand\EE{\@ifnextchar* 
       {\@firstoftwo{\E}} 
       {\@ifnextchar[ {\E} {\E*}}}
\makeatother%
```

which seems to work. Is there a better way?

Also, how would I go about defining a version of `DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` that does the previous two steps? So that I can define `\EE` with one command, i.e.,  with default `\left`-`\right`,

Comment: You don't want to apply `\left` and `\right` automatically in every situation. Trust me.

Comment: Agreeing with egreg here, you might think it is useful now, but you'll learn later. For example `$\E{something}$` will easily get too big if the fences are auto scaled, thus disturbing the line spacing. Nowadays I only use auto scaling for less than 5% of all of the scaled fences in the manuscripts I edit.